# How to set query which has condition not in?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

How to set query which has condition not in ?
I get from client list of ids (ids is list of numbers) and I need to returns only one user with different id (id of new user is not in passed list).

```
user =  session.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.level.in_(ids)).first()
```

How to change this query to return first user which is not in ( at the moment it is first which is in) ?

Answer (score 4):

SQLAlchemy uses `~` for "not":

```
user =  session.query(UserModel).filter(~UserModel.level.in_(ids)).first()
```

Comment: There is also the `not_` function which does the same thing: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_